# Collection Framework

Tags: collections, java

Difference between HashSet and TreeSet?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the JavaDoc of both classes. They are different in various aspects.

As an example, ordering:

- [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. **The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used**.

- [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set
>   interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). **It
>   makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over
>   time.** This class permits the null
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Java Tutorials trail on [Set Implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html), from which I quote:

> `HashSet` is much faster than
>   `TreeSet` (constant-time versus
>   log-time for most operations) but
>   offers no ordering guarantees. If you
>   need to use the operations in the
>   `SortedSet` interface, or if
>   value-ordered iteration is required,
>   use `TreeSet`; otherwise, use
>   `HashSet`. It's a fair bet that you'll
>   end up using `HashSet` most of the
>   time.